How to correct measure memory usage of multi-threading in R language by shell?
I have a shell script to monitor system resource usage and send alerts. Basically, it relies on the following commands:
ps -u "$user" --no-headers -o pmem | awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum}'

In most cases, it works well, but recently I noticed some issues.
For example, run with a clean rebooted system to minimize the effect of other processes:
# R
library(data.table)
library(parallel)

set.seed(123)
n_rows <- 1e7  
n_cols <- 1000
## memory black hole!!! change it if necessary, however, you need to require a high level of memory usage (about 1/30 to 1/10 of your usable memory) to achieve significant results in the subsequent tests
dt <- data.table(matrix(runif(n_rows * n_cols), nrow = n_rows, ncol = n_cols))

memory_usage <- object.size(dt)
format(memory_usage, units = "auto")

worker_function <- function(data) {
  row_sums <- rowSums(data)
  ## wait about 30s and run shell command to test when process sleep
  Sys.sleep(1000)
  return(row_sums)
}

n_threads <- 10
results <- mclapply(1:n_threads, function(x) worker_function(dt), mc.cores = n_threads)

check memory status by top
top


we can get memory usage precent by sum of the MEM% col, or by following command:
ps -u "$user" --no-headers -o pmem | awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum}'
# 113.9

In my system (1.5 TiB memory and 2.0 GiB swap) you will find this value larger than 100, but if you check memory by free -h, you will get:

only 645/1500 Gib be used, it less than 50%

This will never be an accurate number (allocation, freeing, garbage collection etc) across the different programs (top, free, htop, ps etc.) but maybe see here from the author of htop.

But the difference in the data seems to be too large. I have tested multithreading in other languages, and it seems that I cannot observe such a significant difference

There are many many different concepts that boil down to multithreading. Forking, threads, concurrency... scripting languages (with/w/o precompilation, jit, GIL, etc), compiled languages. Memory usage is never going to be comparable, even within one language with different approaches. Try e.g. using data.table for a mini language that runs parallel internally out of the box. I.e. comparing (OS controlled if not C) memory management between languages and concepts is hugely vague at best.
